# How to fetch the changed object from an array in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 arrays stored in arr1 and arr2

```
var arr1 = [
  {
    "status": 4,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "status": 2,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "status": 1,
    "id": 3
  }];

var arr2 = [{
    "status": 4,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "status": 2,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "status": 4,
    "id": 3
  }];
```

Am using  angular.equals(arr1, arr2) to check 2 arrays are same but when the status changes in arr2, how can i fetch the respective id from arr2.

Comment: *"when the status changes"* ... please provide more details as per [mcve]. Numerous ways to accomplish this depending on use case

Comment: whenever the data from backend changes that is arr2's status, i want to display the respective id's status has changed.

Comment: Where's the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the array which contains the ids of the elements with different status value.

```
 var elementsChanged = arr1.map((val, idx) => {
        if (val.status !== arr2[idx].status)
          return arr2[idx].id
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first put `arr2` in $scope and then set `$watch` on your data to detect the exact id change.
`$scope.$watch('arr2', function(newValue, oldValue){.//iterate and detect your id change..}, true);`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28636/) for watcher

[Demo Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28638/) with @korte map suggestion.